# Horizontal LinearLayout with Multiple Children, Move Children Below on New Line When No More Horizontal Space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I would like to have a horizontal `LinearLayout` that is as wide as the **screen** and as high as its **children**, but the trick is that its children will have dynamic width each and I don't want them going off screen (cut out). I want them to flow/break in a new line so that they are all visible.

*Although totally irrelevant to Android, it should work similar to how inline `<div>`'s work in HTML.*

Here's what I have right now:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="If you would enter some digits in this field " />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="enter some digits here"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" that would be great" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But as soon as the children of the `LinearLayout` get wider than the screen the extra part gets off the screen/invisible.

Comment: I don't think that is doable in Android layout. Unless you implement listeners that measure the width and what not and move views down. The other option is to create a WebView and populate it, I know it is doable like that, however I do not have experience in that aspect. Good Luck.

Comment: Try `ChipGroup`. It is meant to hold `Chip` but it is not limited to that. It can be a container for other views as well. `ChipGroup` has the feature to overflow its views to the next line if they are not fitting in one line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I would like to have a horizontal LinearLayout that is as wide as the
>   screen and as high as its children, but the trick is that its children
>   will have dynamic width each and I don't want them going off screen
>   (cut out).

A `LinearLayout` can't do that(any default layout from the SDK can't do that) because the `LinearLayout` is set to place **all** the children in **one** horizontal or vertical line. Also, any type of conditional layout rules based on dimensions not yet available(like in your case the available width for the `LinearLayout`) are not possible in the xml anyway.

What you need is a custom layout which measures the children to use the available space moving any non fitting children on a new line below(a so called `FlowLayout`).

Edit:

Google now provides the [`flexbox`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) library which implements the web's flexbox layout on Android. Using that library, the children of a `FlexboxLayout` will be placed on multiple lines based on their widths by using the `flexDirection`(with a value of *row*) and `flexWrap`(with a value of *wrap*) attributes.

Comment: broken video link

Comment: @ViperAlpha Yes, the parleys site is gone. I've looked for a replacement video but I couldn't find any. The video was from Chet Haase one of the android SDK developers talking about creating custom views and making a FlowLayout in the process. There are libraries that implement that layout if you needed, libraries like https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: Found out that Google implemented their own: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout , It would be nice for you to add it in your anwer

Comment: @ViperAlpha Yes, that is the library to use. I've edited my answer to point users to Google's library. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Actually ChipGroup can

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Flexbox you could use [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup) which is part of the Material Design Library
The `ChipGroup` can be a container for other components as well, it doesn't have to be a `Chip`, it could be a button etc.

> A ChipGroup is used to hold multiple Chips. By default, the chips are
> reflowed across multiple lines. Set the app:singleLine attribute to
> constrain the chips to a single horizontal line. If you do so, you'll
> usually want to wrap this ChipGroup in a HorizontalScrollView.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="This" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="is" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="a" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="because" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="chip" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipText="group" />


    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

**Updated:**

Starting with `Constraint Layout 2.0` we can now use `Flow`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
   app:constraint_referenced_ids="card1, card2, card3"
   />
```

Notice `app:constraint_referenced_ids`  and `app:flow_wrapMode`

First one is about passing the views and the second one about handling the way we wrap them.

Make sure to read about it on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow)

Comment: this is too a good solution. but for recycler view i think the best is to use https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: @Oussaki updated my answer as i found out that constraint layout 2.0 takes care of this problem